# Definition of injectivity

Tags: functions, logic

In the book *Analysis*, Terrence Tao defines an injective function as follows:

> A function f is one-to-one
> (or injective) if different elements map to different elements:
> $$x \neq x' \Longrightarrow f(x) \neq f(x') $$
> Equivalently, a function is one-to-one if
> $$ f(x) = f(x') \Longrightarrow x = x'$$

Why the converse of the two statements is not true? Why can't we consider

$$x = x' \Longrightarrow f(x) = f(x') $$

or

$$ f(x) \neq f(x') \Longrightarrow x \neq x'$$

Comment: You can consider it, but it doesn't tell you the function is injective: it tells you it is well-defined/a function (does not try to send the same thing to two different things).

Answer (score 2):

$x = x' \implies f(x) = f(x')$ and its contrapositive $f(x) \ne f(x') \implies x\ne x'$

These statements suggest that every input maps to a unique output.

This is true for all functions and not just injective functions.

Comment: I agree with the first statement saying that every input maps to a unique output. But I don't really see it for the second statement. The way I see it, it states that if I have 2 different mappings, they have to come from different inputs, which would be consistent with the definition of injectivity. What am I missing?

Comment: Sure different outputs suggest different inputs.  But that doesn't mean that there are not multiple inputs mapping to the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Say $A$ and $B$ are sets. A function $f\colon A\to B$ from $A$ to $B$ can be thought of as a collection of ordered pairs $(x,y)$, with $x\in A$ and $y\in B$, with the following two properties:

1. If $(x,y)$ and $(x,y')$ are both in $f$, then $y=y'$.
2. For every $a\in A$ there is at least one $b\in B$ such that $(a,b)$ is in $f$.

We then think of the pair $(a,b)$ as telling us that "$f(a)=b$". The first condition tells you the function does not try to send the same element to different things; the second condition tells you every element of $A$ goes somewhere in $B$.

If we reverse each of these conditions, we get special properties for functions:

3. If $(x,y)$ and $(x',y)$ are both in $f$, then $x=x'$.
4. For every $b\in B$ there is at least one $a\in A$ such that $(a,b)$ is in $f$.

Condition 3 tells you the function is injective (if $f(x)=y$ and $f(x')=y$, i.e., if $f(x)=f(x')$, then $x=x'$). Condition 4 tells you the function is *surjective*. So reversing the conditions for "is a function" gives you the conditions for "is injective" and "is surjective." Or said another way, you *can* "reverse" the implication for "injective", and it gives you something sensible: it's just that what it gives you is one of the conditions that must be satisfied in order for you to have a function in the first place.